# php split using stream_get_line after a keyword

Tags: php, file

I have a file which looks something like this:

```
   # Hand 1: Tournament
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text

   # Hand 2: Knockout
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text


   # Hand 3: Knockout
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text


   # Hand 4: Tournament
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text


   # Hand 5: Tournament
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
```

The file is 400mb and i want to split it into files around 400kb or so, im not sure if there is a way to split by kb or not so i decided to just do it by line since it doesnt need to be very accurate as long as its between 400-500kb.

Now i dont want it to split in the middle of a block so when it reaches 100 lines i want it to split just before the # Hand part so i dont end up with an incomplete block.

Ive tried using this code but im getting an error and i cant find much online documentation to compare mine to. Any ideas what is wrong.

The end result im aiming at is to split after x lines and create tons of 400kb docs instead of a 400mb one.

```
<?php
$filename = fopen('files/text1.txt','r');
$keyword = 'Hand #';

$contents = stream_get_line($filename,100,$keyword);

?><pre><?php
print_r($contents);
?></pre><?php

?>
```

The error i get is:
PHP Warning:  stream_get_line() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: Parsing and editing 400MB files in PHP... What's your memory limit?

Answer (score 0):

I made my own recursive code snippet with so many testing cases to achieve the best results at the end for this topic. I wish comments tell you the things that should be told.

```
<?php
/* Snippet by Revo */
$file = file('your-file.txt'); // files content goes to an array line by line
$count = count($file); // number of all lines
$length = 500; // the least line to split (here on every 500 lines, but it may be splitted on lines 501, 502, 503, ... based on where is the next boundary)
$boundary = "# Hand"; // boundary word

/**
 * [split_file split the whole txt file]
 * @param  [int] $old_length     [length to begin job, default is 0]
 * @param  [int] $current_length [length to end job]
 * @param  [string] $boundary       [group of characters that we check on every call]
 * @param  [int] $filename       [that's for having autamated file name in numbers]
 * @return [true]                 [always returns true]
 */
function split_file($old_length, $current_length, $boundary, $filename)
{
    global $count, $file, $length;
    if(@strpos($file[$current_length], $boundary) === false) // check if at current length we can end it up or not
    {
        if($current_length < $count) // check if current length is lower than total
        {
            if($length <= $count - $current_length)
            {
                $split = array_slice($file, $current_length, $count); // split the lines to check for nearest line that has our word boudary
                foreach ($split as $key => $value)
                {
                    if(strpos($value, $boundary) !== false)
                    {
                        $new_length = $current_length + $key; // change the new length for next split
                        $length += $key;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $new_length = $count;
                $length = $count - $current_length;
            }
        }
        else if($current_length == $count)
        {
            // this is the block that will run on the last call
            $new_length = $count;
            $length = $current_length - $old_length;
        }
    }
    else
        $new_length = $current_length;

    $split = array_slice($file, $old_length, $length);
    $old_length = $new_length; // change the old length
    $next_length = $new_length + $length; // change the next length
    file_put_contents($filename.".txt", print_r($split, true)); // put content on a new file
    if($new_length == $count)
    {
        // if we are on the last job don't continue anymore
        return true;
    }
    if($next_length > $count) // for that last call check if length will goes higher than total
    {
        $next_length = $count;
    }
    split_file($old_length, $next_length, $boundary, ++$filename);
}

# Here we go
split_file($old_length = 0, $length, $boundary, 0);
?>
```

If `.txt` file contains this:

```
  # Hand 0: Tournament
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text

   # Hand 2: Knockout
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text


   # Hand 3: Knockout
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text


   # Hand 4: Tournament
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text


   # Hand 5: Tournament
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
```

Output for the below settings are stored at 6 `.txt` file as shown.

```
$length = 2; // Or 3,4,5 [without changing in result]
$boundary = "# Hand";
```

**Output:**

***0.txt***

```
  # Hand 0: Tournament
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
```

***1.txt***

```
  # Hand 1: Tournament
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
```

***2.txt***

```
   # Hand 2: Knockout
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
```

***3.txt***

```
   # Hand 3: Knockout
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
```

***4.txt***

```
   # Hand 4: Tournament
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
```

***5.txt***

```
   # Hand 5: Tournament
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
   Lots of placeholder text
```

Comment: Since im dealing with a 400mb file, wouldnt $file = file load the whole 400mb into memory, theres a good chance im wrong but i got the impression that stream_get_line just loads the 100 lines into memory, then i can access it do what i need and load another 100. I appreciate the time and effort on this reply so just wanted to confirm if it would be compatible with large files.